# Print & Print Preview a Bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, print-preview, printdialog

I have made a program that draws on a image on a picturebox and now i want to print and print preview this, but don't know how. Please Help,

Thanks

**EDIT**
I have tried using print and print preview dialogs but don't know how to work them properly to print and show the contents of a picturebox and its image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop a PrintDocument on your form.  You'll want a PrintPreviewDialog and PrintDialog as well.  Set the dialogs' Document property to the PrintDocument.  Implement the PrintPage event handler for it, could be a simple as:

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0);
    }
```

And add buttons or menu items to call the dialogs' ShowDialog() method.

Comment: I have done this but it still does not show the image in the picturebox for some reason?

Comment: You are not using CreateGraphics() in your drawing code, are you?  If you use the PB's Paint event then move the drawing code into a separate method, one that takes a Graphics argument, and call that code from your PrintPage event handler.  Pass e.Graphics